# How to pass Array List from one servlet to another?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I have a result.jsp file that returns a list of result from a query and displayed it on a table. This processing is done from a "Extract" servlet. And I have a button below that will call the "Final" servlet that will write the result to a file.

How can I pass the resultList to the "Final" servlet?

```
<div class="content">      
     <table border="1" class="blueTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>EMPLOYEE ID</th>
                <th>EMPLOYEE NAME</th>
                <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
                <th>OFFICE NUMBER</th>
                <th>SALARY</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <c:forEach items="${resultList}" var="item">
            <tr>
                <td>${item.employeeId}</td>
                <td>${item.employeeName}</td>
                <td>${item.department}</td>
                <td>${item.officeNumber}</td>
                <td>${item.salary}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>    
</div>

 <div>
    <span>Extract Directory:&nbsp;</span>
    <span><input type="text" id="filepath" name="filepath" size="40"/></span>       
 </div>
 <br/>
 <div>
    <span >Extract File Name:</span>
    <span><input type="text" id="filename" name="filename" size="40"/></span>       
 </div>
 <br/>
<form action="Final" method="post">
     <span><input type="submit" name="extractButton" value="EXTRACT"/></span>
</form>
```

**Extract Servlet**

```
 List<Result> resultList = executeQueryOnMessageTable1();

   if(!resultList.isEmpty()) { 
       request.setAttribute("resultList", resultList);
   }

   RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp");
   req.forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the setAttribute method.

```
 request.setAttribute("result", resultList);
```

And i don't know why you are using request dispatcher, if you want to call the servlet upon click of the button.

Access the Array List in the final servlet as

```
ArrayList<String> list=(ArrayList<List>)request.getAttribute("result"); //don't forget to type cast, as the getAttribute returns object.
```

If you want to call final servlet right after you get the resulList, use request.include to get the values in final servlet.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/servleturl").include(request, response);
```